# Watermark width issue on smaller images using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation

I am using Image manipulation library with Codeigniter for image resize and watermark which seems ok except watermark on small get too bigger,Is there any way to keep watermark on every image with same dimensions regardless of the uploaded image size.

Please have a look at my generate watermarks

https://ibb.co/m5sojf

https://ibb.co/jR6sAL

Here is my Code below

//Controller

```
 $this->manipulate_img->watermark($data['full_path']);
 $this->manipulate_img->resize($data['full_path'],$path.'thumbs',780,400);
```

// Manipulation Library

```
public function resize($pic_path,$two,$width,$height)
    {
        $config['source_image'] = $pic_path;
        $config['new_image'] = $two;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = $width;
       // $config['height'] = $height;
        $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->CI->image_lib->resize();
        $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
        return true;
    }

    public function watermark($pic_path)
    {
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $pic_path;
        $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/img/test.png';
        $config['wm_opacity'] = 50;
        $config['width'] = '330';
        $config['height'] = '100';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
        $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->CI->image_lib->watermark();
        $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: can you try width in percentage?

Comment: Nope, i will try this one @Sachin

Comment: Its not working by applying width in percentage @Sachin

Comment: Then need to find your main image size and according to image size set your watermark image size